# Setting up profile for invalid SSL Certificates using Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: cucumber, webdriver, ssl-certificate, capybara

-=UPDATE=-

The problem I was experiencing was a case where the certificate was valid, but the site was invalid for the certificate. Leaving the default settings (either providing a profile with the certificate default settings or using the standard :selenium driver in Capybara) worked for my case. I mistakingly thought I needed to modify my Firefox profile for the driver to work, this wasn't the case.

Removing the certificate settings from my custom profile fixed the issue. Thanks Jarib.

-=Original Question=-

I'm currently trying to setup my test browsers to ignore invalid SSL certificates when using Cucumber and Capybara. I have the following in my env.rb:

```ruby
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_profile do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.secure_ssl = false
  profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end 

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :selenium_profile
  config.default_wait_time = 15
end
```

The environment seems to be setup properly, and the testcase runs fine until I hit an invalid certificate.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the code above? Is there another option (using script/code) to create a new profile that ignores certificates? I'm trying to do some black box testing on a qa site, so self signed certificates aren't really an option. Individual Firefox profiles aren't good since the code needs to be portable. Thoughts?

Environment:

```
OS X.7.3
Firefox 12.0
ruby-1.9.2
capybara (1.1.2 ruby, 0.4.1.2)
capybara-webkit (0.8.0)
cucumber (1.1.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.21.2)
```

Comment: secure_ssl is false by default, so you don't need to set that. Does it fail when you leave "profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = true" (also the default) as well? If so, seeing screenshots of the error pages (with details expanded) would be helpful.

Comment: Well, I feel a bit sheepish, you are right. The defaults are working if you register a profile (with no individual settings) or if you register the default :selenium driver. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without `profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false`
and with  `profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True`